# Sublime 3 not interfacing with R (tried R-box and REPL)

Tags: r, sublimetext3

Super basic question here:

I installed the R-box package in Sublime 3 with no problems. 
I changed the path to my R.app in the SublimeREPL.sublime-settings in Sublime, although this should not make a differece on Mac.
I checked in Package Control -> R-Box:Select Program. It's set to R.

I'm simply unable to get Sublime to send code to R. Pressing Cmd+Enter does nothing (actually, it starts a new line on Sublime).

I'm running Sublime 3 on Maverics, and R version 3.2.1. But I had the same problems with Sublime 2 and a previous R version. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't find any more information in the installation page.

Comment: You may want to add this as an issue on the github repo if you're still having the problem https://github.com/randy3k/R-Box/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I got an answer from the R-box developers, that worked perfectly:
Close Sublime Text 3, then reopen it. Then check that at the bottom right of the window it says R Extended.

If not, you need to set the Syntax on the file:

cmd+shift+P
Set Syntax: R Extended

Answer (score 2):

Open up an R console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P and typing REPL R (after a few times you’ll be able to just type R and it will come up). You can open up two windows using (Alt+Shift+2) so you can have your R code on the left and your R console on the right.

As for running the code, once you have called the R console, you have three options: To run the current line or your selected lines, press Ctrl+Shift (release) then l. To run just the selected text, press Ctrl+Shift (release) then s. To run the entire file, press Ctrl+Shift (release) then f.

Comment: Thanks! I have no problems opening the R console. Again I feel really dumb but pressing any of the combinations doesn't send the code to R. I just get an 's', or 'l' written on my code.

Comment: Actually, please ignore my previous comment. It does work now.. (sort of). The code doesn't get immediately evaluated, but I have to go to the other window where the console is, and hit Enter. Is this behaviour expected? Thanks again and sorry for the silly questions!

Comment: Hey, I am having the same problem as you mentioned above. Do you remember what you did in order to not have the selected line simply be replaced by 's' when pressing it, but be evaluated in the console?

Comment: Hi, I also have the same problem. Everytime I do Ctrl+Shift (release) then s, it simply replaces the code by an s.